# Unresolved Inclusion in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, g++, eclipse-cdt, centos7

I have read:
[unresolved external symbol in eclipse cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641912/unresolved-external-symbol-in-eclipse-cdt) and [Unresolved inclusion in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062435/unresolved-inclusion-in-eclipse)

I am using Eclipse CDT Neon Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

Eclipse CDT can compile my code but for some reason, it highlights

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
```

as "Unresolved inclusion".

I have already set the include path for my GCC compiler (in properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Includes) to have /opt/boost, which symlinks to /opt/boost_1_63_0.  It is accessible too:

```
$ ll /opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser myuser 1061 Dec 22  2016 /opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp
```

I also noticed that #include statements for other headers in /opt also have the same issue.

Any idea how to fix this?

I tried to rebuild the index few times.  Same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the header files directly in `/opt/boost`? Or possibly in `/opt/boost/include`? Can you yourself open e.g. `/opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp`?

Comment: yes, ll /opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser myuser 1061 Dec 22  2016 /opt/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp